# Transitive relation in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I just want to know if transitive relation(i don't know if it can be called so) can be persisted in hibernate using annotations.
ie, i have 3 pojo classes namely A,B and C.
i just map C's instance into B and B's instance into A.
when i save A (session.save(A)), can i get B and C persisted?

For example:

```
a = new A();

b = new B();

c = new C();

b.setC(c);

a.setB(b)

then,

session.save(a);
```

if the above line execute, i just want to know whether b and c would get persisted?

i think all of you got it what i meant.
Else, i can more elaborate my problem..
Please help me..
Thanks in advance.

Comment: such operations are called cascading operations

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comments.... But i just want to know whether b and c would get persisted automatically? I think cascade can flow in one level ie, from a to b or b to c...right? Here i want to persist a,b and c.... Is it possible in hibernate?

Comment: you will have to add cascade at both levels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define what object to save along with your current object. In your case

**For A** When A is saved, save the B object along with it.

```
public class A {
    @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST})
    B b;
}
```

**For B** When B is saved, save the C object automatically along with it

```
public class B {
    @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST})
    private C c;
}
```

**For C** (Nothing to save along with it)

```
public class C {

}
```

Comment: Ok i agreed. But, if an object of A (say 'a') will be persisted, then could b and c get persisted automatically?

Comment: Yes, it will. That's the whole purpose of CascadeType.PERSIST

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have b and c persisted as well when a is being persisted. It all depends on your mapping, have a look at [JEE's CascadeType](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/CascadeType.html) or [Hibernate's @Cascade Annotation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/engine/Cascade.html)